# Find the correct instance of a Json message from a set of POJO's

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind

I have a JsonString, for e.g.

```
{"TestMessage":"This test is awesome"}
```

and I have a set of POJO's for e.g.

TestMessage, TestOther, TestSomethingElse

What I need is something which can detect the type of the Json String, so that i can manipulate data with the correct Pojo.

I can do something similar with XML data as follows

```
Unmarshaller u = MatchHelper.createMarshaller();
  JAXBElement<AbstractMessageType> eventElement = (JAXBElement<AbstractMessageType>)
      u.unmarshal(new StringReader(xmlMessage));
  if (eventElement.getValue() instanceof TestMessage) {
    TestMessage returnRecord = (TestMessage) eventElement.getValue();
    return returnRecord;
  }else if(eventElement.getValue() instanceof TestOther){
      .....
      .....
  }
```

I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
JsonNode eventNode = null;
try {
  eventNode = this.mapper.readTree(message);
}catch (JsonParseException e){
  log.error("Json Parse Exception - {}",e);
}

if(eventNode!= null && eventNode.isPojo()){
  POJONode x = (POJONode)eventNode;
  if(x.getPojo() instanceof TestMessage){
    log.info("This is a Test Message");
    TestMessage testMessage = this.mapper.readValue(message, TestMessage.class);
  }
}
```

Comment: JSON doesn't work like XML and thus you can't do it in a similar way. Your JSON object just defines the object has one field called `TestMessage` which has the string value `"This test is awesome"`. Unless _you_ provide some information on how to parse that Jackson can't know what this is. One way you could try would be to provide a pojo that contains fields like `TestMessage testMessage` etc., tell Jackson to ignore missing fields and change your JSON to `{"testMessage":"..."}`. (You'd not have to change the JSON but having a field `TestMessage TestMessage` is a receipe for many errors).

Comment: Thanks for the input, it seems it is indeed tricky. One other way I can think and probably work with is exception handling but I know that's the worst way I can code something although if nothing works I m inclined to parse my Json by Handling exceptions.

Comment: By the way my Pojo's are like that, the messages are generated using the same pojo's at the source end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jackson one can make use of `@JsonTypeInfo`, which provides you the ability to specify a discriminator for distinct types.
Maybe this article might help you as well: [JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization)

Coming back to your example and assuming that you can control the message format, this could be your model:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
public abstract class AbstractMessage {
}

public class TestMessage extends AbstractMessage {
  private String message;
  ...
}

public class TestOther extends AbstractMessage {
  private int other;
  ...
}

public class TestSomethingElse extends AbstractMessage {
  private boolean justSomethingElse;
  ...
}
```

Forgot to mention that your initial approach using JAXB would work in this case, but you could directly unmarshal to `AbstractMessage` instead of `JAXBElement` and then do your handling of concrete subtypes.

Comment: I read and added the @JsonTypeInfo annotation as well, but I am still not sure how to go about next and test it.

Comment: Have a look at this sample [json-type-info project](https://github.com/ffray/json-type-info)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the sample, I had to change my json schema quite a bit and then I struggled with Wrapping and Unwrapping Root Values with Jackson but finally made it work. Thanks a lot.